# How to ensure at compile time that a type will serialize into a JSON array?

Tags: rust, serde

I have a trait that I use as an interface to Rails' ActiveJob; I want my Rust backend to fire jobs to be processed by a Rails API:

```
trait BackgroundJob {
    type Args: Serialize;
    const QUEUE: &'static str;
    const CLASS: JobClass;

    fn payload(self) -> Self::Args;
}
```

An example implementation of the trait:

```
impl BackgroundJob for MyJob {
    type Args = (String,);
    const QUEUE: &'static str = "my_queue";
    const CLASS: JobClass = JobClass::Job1;

    fn payload(self) -> Self::Args {
        (self.payload,)
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=70ad53bc61eb7d40aae0dbf1dca0f96c&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

In my application the code is a little bit more complex (specifically, I have an Actix actor instead of the generic function over `BackgroundJob`) but the idea is the same.

This code works fine but I have to make sure that all the implementations of `BackgroundJob` will have as the `Args` type parameter something that will serialize to a JSON array (to work with active job).

What I would like to do is to have a compile-time guarantee that `Args` will serialize to an array. Is that possible?

I tried to work around with `SerializeTuple` and `SerializeSeq` traits from Serde but without success.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When you say "make your own" do you means something like defining a trait (`SeralizeToArray` for example) and implement it for structures that I "know" (tuples, vec, etc) that they will be serialized to an array?

Comment: I've been able to define this trait and provide implementations for tuples and array using macros plus one implementation for Vec. It seems to do the job for what I need because the job parameters will mostly be tuples since they are not likely to be of the same type.
Thanks!
P.S. How can I mark this question as resolved? Should I answer my own question with the solution I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the answer is "no, there's nothing native to Serde to do this". There's no trait corresponding to this specific need.

You could make your own *marker trait* and require that it be present, but it wouldn't be automatically implemented by anything; you'd have to manually implement it for any valid type. I'm guessing it wouldn't be what you want:

```
trait SerializeToJsonArray {}

impl<T> SerializeToJsonArray for Vec<T> {}
impl<T> SerializeToJsonArray for [T] {}
impl<A> SerializeToJsonArray for (A, ) {}
impl<A, B> SerializeToJsonArray for (A, B, ) {}
impl<A, B, C> SerializeToJsonArray for (A, B, C, ) {}
// etc.

trait BackgroundJob {
    type Args: Serialize + SerializeToJsonArray;
}
```

This is also trivially breakable — you can easily implement `SerializeToJsonArray` for types that **don't** serialize to an array. Likewise, Serde doesn't know about this trait and you'll still need to handle non-arrays at serialization time.

Comment: Thanks, this is not perfect as you said because I can still implement SerializeToArray for anything but it stills prevent the most common potential problem which is to forgot to have a tuple as `Args` when the job takes only one parameter.